# Extract by mask, default naming and arcpy

Tags: arcpy, python

The [extract by mask tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/extract-by-mask.htm) in ArcGIS has only two required arguments. The first is `inRaster` and the second is `inMaskData`. The filename and format of the output raster are determined automatically. The following command will achieve this:

```
extracted_raster = arcpy.gp.ExtractByMask_sa(input_raster, extraction_buffer)
```

The output raster automatically gets a name like so: `Extract_{in_raster_name}`. It gets dumped into `arcpy.env.workspace` as expected.

In my case, I want my output raster to get dumped into `in_memory`, but I also want `arcpy` to automatically name it and pick the format for me. I tried doing this using two methods. The first consists of changing the workspace to `in_memory` before I run the above command:

```
   arcpy.env.workspace = 'in_memory'
   extracted_raster = arcpy.gp.ExtractByMask_sa(input_raster, extraction_buffer)
```

This throws an error, since it cannot find my input_raster, which is not located `in_memory`:

> ERROR 000865: Input raster: .\input\elsus.tif does not exist. Failed
>   to execute (ExtractByMask).

The second method is to hardcode the `output_raster` location to `in_memory`. But using this method does not allow me to force `arcpy` to name the file:

```
arcpy.gp.ExtractByMask_sa(input_raster, extraction_buffer, r'in_memory\test')
```

I really don't care about the file name for this intermediate data. I prefer to store the features/rasters as objects and use the variable names instead.How can I force `arcpy` to handle the naming of the file, such that I only have to worry about the output object variable name?

Comment: I reuse the output for other in_memory tasks. Basically the situation is as follows, I have two large input datasets that I cannot store in memory. I first set my workspace to the locations of these input datasets and load them into `arcpy.FeatureSet` and `arcpy.Raster` objects. Then I switch my workspace to `in_memory` and want to start doing my work there. However I want to still be able to invoke the input datasets at will, even if they belong to a different workspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem a different way. It turns out I was using a bit of a weird python setup to actually run my script. This is what I was doing before from `cmd` command line

```
C:\>
C:\> cd C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.6
C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.6> python C:\WorkspaceDirectory\script.py
```

Which meant that I could find no way, from my current directory, to extract the true relative paths of the input features. It always saw `C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.6` as my current working directory which I now see is very bad practice.

Once I added the `C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.6` to my `PATH` variable, I could comfortably use `os.path.abspath` to get the absolute path of the input feature classes. Once the inputs where created using absolute paths, I was perfectly able to do the following:

```
  arcpy.env.workspace = 'in_memory'
  extracted_raster = arcpy.gp.ExtractByMask_sa(input_raster, extraction_buffer)
```

with no issues at all.

Indeed `arcpy` does not account for relative paths. It is therefore essential to define things with absolute paths, and to make sure that python system settings are correctly configured.

Answer (score 1):

You cant have a file extension (for example .tif) for rasters in the in_memory workspace. Remove it and then use Copy Raster to set it when you save to disk.

For arcpy to find input_raster when you change workspace you can do:

```
import os,arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\database.gdb'
rasters = arcpy.ListRasters() #Will only list names, not complete path, so when you change workspace arcpy will not know where they are
rasters = [os.path.join(arcpy.env.workspace, r) for r in rasters] #Add path, now you can change workspace and arcpy will find them anyway
arcpy.env.workspace = r'in_memory'
for r in rasters:
    #do something
```